# Помогите составить алгоритм на python для подбора значений

Tags: python, математика

Есть такое выражение:

```
res = a[i] * b[j] + b[i] * a[j]
```

при этом 1 <= i < j <= n.
a и b - два массива. n - целое число, количество элементов в массиве, вводиться пользователем.
Необходимо найти такие значения i и j, чтобы результат выражения был максимальным.
Таблицы значений(рассчитаны вручную):

```
n = 3
  a = 5, 4, 6
  b = 1, 2, 3
результат = 24
n = 5
  a = 2 3 4 4 5
  b = 5 4 4 3 1
результат = 28
```

Заранее спасибо за внимание!!

Comment: Ну, самое простое - двойной (вложенный) цикл, и вперед...

Comment: @EOF это значит что j может быть или больше или равна n, то есть использовать последний или любой другой  элемент массива, который больше i.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что у нас два массива `a` и `b`?

Comment: @roddar92, да правильно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы все же делал так (в меру моего незнания python):

```
mx = arr1[0]*arr2[1]+arr2[0]*arr1[1]
ip = 0
jp = 1
for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(arr2)):
        r = arr1[i]*arr2[j]+arr2[i]*arr1[j]
        if r > mx:
            mx = r
            ip = i
            jp = j
print(ip,jp,mx)
```

Просто для сравнения с ответом roddar92 - судите о правильности сами - https://ideone.com/bHNQYT

Comment: Спасибо, в общем-то работает, только при n <= 1000 выдаёт неправильный ответ. Если можете, то пожалуйста дополните решение.

Comment: Т.е. ответ, приведенный по ссылке, неправильный? Там n явно меньше 1000... Ну что за разговор, в самом деле... *При таких-то входных данных ваш ответ такой-то, должен быть таким-то* А так - что мне искать?

Comment: Он частично правильный, также  извините за опечатку. Я хотел написать n = 1000.

Comment: Словом, как вы понимаете, для исправления мне нужны точные входные данные . Вы же как-то обнаружили ошибку? Покажите ее мне, буду исправлять... Только конкретную ошибку, а не просто "не работает".

Comment: я взял данные, результат который уже рассчитан и многократно повторил. таким образом количество элементов в массивах было равно по 1000. По идее максимальное значение выражения не должно меняться. Входные данные предоставлены выше(Без повторения). Результат был 23 а не 28.

Comment: Конкретные данные - какое именно из слов здесь непонятно? Откуда мне знать, что вы там считали, верно или нет. Давайте эти массивы, положите где-то на файлообменник, дайте ссылку - тогда будет о чем говорить.

Comment: @Саня вы не правы, т.к. результат поменяется при "повторении".

Comment: Если речь об этом - https://ideone.com/MrX74f - то результат меняется...

Answer (score 0):

Для одного массива алгоритм будет прост:

```
arr1 = [2, 1, 5, 3, 8, -1, 3]
arr2 = [-1, 3, 5, 6, 0, -1, 5]

max_product, i_pos, j_pos = arr1[0], 0, 0
for i, el in enumerate(arr1):
    for j, el2 in enumerate(arr2):
        if el * el2 + arr1[j] * arr2[i] > max_product:
            max_product = el * el2 + arr1[j] * arr2[i]
            i_pos, j_pos = i, j

print(i_pos, j_pos, max_product)
```

Ответ: 2, 2, 50

Comment: Ой что-то вы не то делаете... У вас нет "перекрестного" умножения и суммирования...

Comment: извините, но не то

Comment: Ой, действительно.. Прошу прощения)